# Add module in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, operating-system

I'm trying to add module in Linux kernel 
In the module entry point, create a linked list containing five struct birthday
elements and then delete this module 
when I compile  next code, screen show this message ( no target specified and no makefile found . stop )  please help me what error ?? and what this message mean and how i can solve problem
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
#define NUM_OF_PERSON    5

/* Example struct we will use. */
typedef struct _birthday {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    struct list_head list;
}birthday;

/* Declare and init the head of the linked list. */
LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);

/* This function is called when the module is loaded. */
int birthdayList_init(void)
{
           printk(KERN_INFO “Loading Module\n”);

    /* Allocate 5 birthdays from kernel */
    birthday *person;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PERSON; i++)
    {
        /* Request malloc to the kernel. */
        person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
        /* Assign value to the struct. */
        person->day = i+1;
        person->month = i+1;
        person->year = i+1;
        /* Init the list within the struct. */
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);
        /* Add this struct to the tail of the list. */
        list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO “Display the list:\n”);

    /* Go thru the list and print. */
    birthday *ptr;
    list_for_each_entry(ptr, &birthday_list, list)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO “day: %d, month: %d, year: %d\n”,
                ptr->day,
                ptr->month,
                ptr->year);
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO “Display done\n”);

           return 0;
}

/* This function is called when the module is removed. */
void birthdayList_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO “Removing Module\n”);

    /* Go thru the list and free the memory. */
    birthday *ptr, *next;
    list_for_each_entry_safe(ptr, next, &birthday_list, list)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO “Removing – day: %d, month: %d, year: %d\n”,
                ptr->day,
                ptr->month,
                ptr->year);
        list_del(&ptr->list);
        kfree(ptr);
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO “Memory free done\n”);
}

/* Macros for registering module entry and exit points. */
module_init( birthdayList_init );
module_exit( birthdayList_exit );

MODULE_LICENSE(“GPL”);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(“BirthdayList Module”);
MODULE_AUTHOR(“daveti”);
```

Comment: you need to have a file named 'makefile' if you are using make to compile the program using make utility. Basically makefile contains  a list of commands that are executed by gcc in a staged manner, usually used when it is cumbersome to type out and link intermediate changes together. Please read about make and understand what you are doing before you do anything

Comment: Read one of the first chapters of "Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition." Building and inserting a kernel module is explained there. Great book, BTW. Next edition coming out soon!